# Sql huge insert script

Tags: oracle, toad

I took a backup of a table in the form of insert script using toad for oracle. I could not use that script in toad to perform inserts because of the huge size. Is there a way that i can run the huge script using toad?

Comment: Cant it be exported or save as SQL*Loader feature ? It is more efficient.

Comment: The problem is I exported it and truncated the table. Now i don't have additional backup :(

Comment: oops, actually table copy people used to take using create table temp as select * from sourcetable; And still, you can also give a try using SQL Plus and run the script.

Comment: so just run it from sqlplus?

Comment: Open the script in an editor and cut it into smaller pieces and run them separately? Not sure what you mean by "huge".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Reduce network time by running the script on the server.**  Chances are the vast majority of the time is spent waiting for the network.  Normally each `INSERT` statement is a separate round-trip.

**2. Reduce network time by batching the inserts.**  Wrap a `begin` and `end;` around a large number of inserts.  A PL/SQL block only requires one round-trip.  Note that you probably cannot put the *entire* script in a single anonymous block as there are parsing limits.  You will get DIANA errors with anonymous blocks larger than roughly a few megabytes in size.

**3. Run the code indirectly.**  Maybe just loading the file in Toad is the problem?  Run a script that simply calls that script, perhaps something like `@my_script.sql`?

Without knowing more about Toad or what the script looks like I cannot say for sure if these will work.  But I've used these approaches with similar issues, there is usually a way to make simplistic install scripts run more than 10 times faster.

Comment: I agree with all these. Very true. But Sorry, isnt it much theory for the OPs question.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar Yes, we need more information about the environment to give a more definitive answer.  For example, a sample of the INSERTs, why exactly it cannot be used in TOAD, etc.

Comment: I tried to run the script from sqlplus but it was throwing an error. Initially i did some fancy stuff using editor may be it picked up a white space or something. However, later i could run the file using sqldeveloper using @my_script.sql. Thanks to everyone for the suggestions. Appreciate it :)

Comment: Wrapping several thousand `insert` statements with `begin` and `end;` worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try running the script in SQLPLUS using '@'

Comment: more details in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31560367/how-to-run-sql-file-in-oracle-sql-developer-tool-to-import-database

Answer (score 0):

1. from the *View* menu, show the *Project Manager*.
2. add sql files to the project
3. select the files, right click and choose *Execute*

[image: see screenshot]